# Why is OpenCV crashing when I use it with threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, python-multithreading

I'm working on a project where I have to run an image classifier on the frames from a live video feed with opencv. Now, I also have to get input from the user, to run various other functions. However, getting inputs on the same loop I'm updating the opencv frames wont work, as the input fuctions pauses the whole program.

For example-

```
import cv2

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def background():
        ret, frame= cam.read()
        cv2.imshow("Screen", frame)




while True:
    background()
    text=input("->\t")
    if text=="quit":
        break
        
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So what I've done is, I've made the `background` fuctions, threaded, by using the library **threading**, so that it could run independently.

Here's the code-

```
import threading
import cv2

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def background():
        while True:
            ret, frame= cam.read()
            cv2.imshow("Screen", frame)


threading1 = threading.Thread(target=background)
threading1.start()

while True:
    text=input("->\t")
    if text=="quit":
        break
        
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But upon running, the OpenCv window crashes. Though the input fuctions is working :/

Here's the screenshot-
[image]

Someone please help me fix this :D

Comment: where is `waitKey` ?

Comment: I thought that would be unneccesary, but give me a second

Comment: Oh god! I'm such an idiot! It works now. I feel very stupid, and i'm sorry! Thanks! @YunusTemurlenk

Answer (score 1):

Just adding waitkey, in the background function fixes it.